# find out origin of script call

Tags: wordpress, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

When loading a website I get this warning and I can't find the origin of the call:

[image]

In the network pane I found that it was initiated by **js:45**, but I have no idea where js:45 is coming from:

[image]

At this point I'm stuck.

It is a WordPress site and I can't seem to find the function/plugin which loads those scripts.

Any ideas how to find the function that originally loads those scripts?

Comment: can you give us that link?

Comment: https://chargetech.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the script that is being loaded and will eventually log that warning due to a missing API key.

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/4/intl/en_gb/common.js"></script>`

You'd need to look for the file that this `script` tag is in on your server. It's not possible for us to work out which file it is originating in on the client, as the server will send a generated response from multiple resources on the server.

Comment: Thanks mate! I was so caught up with finding the solution in the debugger that I didn't scan the source code properly. Fixing it was easy now.